# Simulate a realistic statistical distribution of a coin machine

Tags: c, statistics, simulation, poisson

Say I have 3 different coin types. Example: 10p, 50p and 1£.
I know the average of the numbers of inserted coins for each type along the day:

- 10p: 50 between 10AM and 4PM, 30 in the rest of the day
- 50p: 30 between 11AM and 7PM, 10 in the rest of the day
- 1£: 10 between 1PM and 3PM, 2 in the rest of the day

In my code I have a function that is called every second:

```
typedef enum
{
    none,
    p10,
    p50,
    P1
} CoinType;

CoinType toosCoin(time_t now) // called every second
{
    CoinType coin = none;
    // do some math

    return coin;
}
```

I want to simulate the distribution described by the parameters above, but I'm not sure what is the best approach neither the right distribution(s) to use.

The code will then activate a physical I/O line, according to the selected coin (if any) to trigger an input on an electronic board. This is a "stress-test" of both hardware and firmware. The distributions are needed to provide realistic data to the firmware.

I guess I need something like a Poisson distribution, but I don't understand how to bind the P. parameters to the constraints above.

Comment: There is no enough description there to do a proper job. Is this a class assignment? There should be more to it.

Comment: It's not a class assignment!!! I said in the question. I developed an hardware board and I need to trigger its inputs to stress-test it in a realistic manner.

Comment: If there a lack of information, it's more useful to tell me what I have to add instead of just downvoting - this unlikely leads to improve the question.

Comment: I did not vote.

Comment: As for information needed, this looks like a very artificial problem. It is not a real-world scenario for the average rate at which a coin is inserted to change suddenly on the hour, nor for different coins to have such different patterns. In the real world, patterns would ebb and flow more smoothly. You or somebody else has constructed an artificial scenario. It includes some decisions not stated in your question. Explaining how this problem came to be—what decisions were made that rssulted in this description—would help clarify.

Comment: Yep, but the question is not about the validity of such a scenario - it's related only how to code it.

Comment: I did not question the “validity” of the problem. I asked for background information. Explaining how this problem came to be—what decisions were made that resulted in this description—would help clarify.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's often the case when building a simulation that you don't have a great deal of detailed information.  For instance, building continuously varying non-homogeneous Poisson processes takes a metric ton of data, while logging counts per hour and seeing similarities doesn't.  That's a good reason to apply design of experiments - you may not know the "real" values for a system, but if you can study how that system is affected by varying them over plausible ranges, you can learn a great deal about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @pjs: Information about the problem belongs in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil When asked Mark clarified that it isn't a class assignment, but it would be silly to expect everybody on SO who isn't doing an assignment to start off their questions with a statement to that effect.  He had already given the context info in the second-to-last paragraph of the question and pointed that out in the comment - no new info there. So what comment are you referring to that adds info which is missing from the question?

Comment: @pjs: Yours. Or the problem statement could simply include that the probabilities in disjoint subintervals are independent and the rate is constant within each listed interval.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My comment was my comment.  Mark is not responsible for what I say, and I don't think I should be editing *his* question to include *my* observations as a simulation modeler.  I felt a comment was exactly what I wanted to make.

Comment: pjs: The problem as stated in the question is incomplete. Further information should be in it. Stack Overflow is for creating a durable repository of questions and answers, not just providing individual assistance. Questions and answers are open to being edited by anybody, not just the original author, and that feature ought to be used to improve questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Then have at it yourself.  As for me, I think the question was sufficient as given.  My comment was directed *at you* to explain why I thought it didn't come across as an artificial scenario.

Comment: @pts: Your comment does not explain why the problem is not artificial. It gives a reason why the problem may have been constructed as it was. Nonetheless, it is still constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a set of [non-homogeneous Poisson processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process), which is the fancy way of saying the rate changes over time.  The amount of time between Poisson occurrences has an exponential distribution with the same rate as the Poisson.  Since you're modeling this with discrete time steps of one second, you can get a very good approximation to the exponential using a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  You just need to convert the rate to seconds, and then to the probability of an occurrence in a given second.

I'll use the 10p coin as an example, the others follow similarly.  There are two distinct rates:  50 coins / 6 hours from 10am to 4pm, and 30 coins / 18 hours for the rest of the day.  Since an hour has 3600 seconds, these convert to per-second rates of 5/2160 and 1/2160, respectively.  These, in turn, can be viewed as the per second probability of getting a coin.  Note that these probabilities are an approximation based on the Poisson assumption that you never get two or more occurrences in a small enough time interval.  I suspect you can argue that that's a reasonable assumption at the one-second level given the mechanics of a coin feed.

If you buy that, then life is easy.  When your function gets called, generate a uniform floating point random number between 0.0 and 1.0.  If it's less than or equal to the probability associated with the current time you got a 10p coin, otherwise you didn't.  (If you prefer integer math instead, generate an int uniformly distributed between 1 and 2160, and if it's less than or equal to 5 between 10am and 4pm, or 1 during the rest of the day, you get a coin.  Just make sure to *not* use modulo 2160 to get the random number, lest you introduce [modulo bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias).)

Lather, rinse, and repeat for the other coin types.  The probabilities will be different but calculated in the same manner.  Just make sure to use separate/independent random numbers for the different coin types.

Comment: You got exactly what I need. Thank you for your very clear explanation. Following your hints I can also add several "windows" with different probabilities along the day or even in different days.

Comment: Sounds good.  Weekdays, weekends, paydays, and large sporting events all tend to be different.